# adding new line with text at the bottom of every opened files in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, newlines

I want to add text at the bottom of every opened file (as a extra line) in notepad++. I know how to add at beginning of the file.

Find what:- (?s).*
Replace with:- YOUR TEXT\r\n$0

which helps me more. but don't know how to add (new line with text) at the bottom.

```
"text hello friend"
"text hello friend"
```

should be changed with new line added at the bottom. like

```
"text hello friend"
"text hello friend"
**"text do not sin friend"**
```

Note "***text do not sin friend***" need to be added as *new line* in multiple files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to add text at the bottom of every opened file (as a extra line) in notepad++

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*+)` - This regular expression selects the whole file, when "matches newline" is enabled.
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\r\n**"text do not sin friend"**`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

Notes:

- The above assumes a file with Windows EOLs `\r\n`
- Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs
- Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

  [image]

**Before**:

```
"text hello friend"
"text hello friend"
```

**After**:

```
"text hello friend"
"text hello friend"
**"text do not sin friend"**
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: it works. you are great. !!!!!!!!!---- thank you so much---!!!!!!!!!.